# How to change the day of scheduled backup?

Tags: magento-1.9, backup, schedule

- Is there a way to modify the way when a schedule backup is going to run?
- let's say every week, can we set it to run during Saturdays instead of Mondays?

Answer (score 2):

Magento by default does not provide any option in admin panel to change it from Mondays to Saturdays

you need to override **Mage_Backup_Model_Config_Backend_Cron** class in your custom module

**Mage_Backup_Model_Config_Backend_Cron::_afterSave()**

Magento creates cron expression in above function while saving system configuration from backend using below code

in **_afterSave** method you can see below code

```
$cronExprArray = array(
    intval($time[1]),                                   # Minute
    intval($time[0]),                                   # Hour
    ($frequency == $frequencyMonthly) ? '1' : '*',      # Day of the Month
    '*',                                                # Month of the Year
    ($frequency == $frequencyWeekly) ? '1' : '*',       # Day of the Week 1 = Monday you need to change it to 6 for Saturdays
);
$cronExprString = join(' ', $cronExprArray);
```

Here Magento is creating cron expression to run cron.

you need to change **'1'** to **'6'** to run cron on Saturdays